# Missing something in order to import fs module with rollup

Tags: rollup

I'm using ES6 import statements along with rollup in my Node app and running into difficulties. For example, when trying to load fs:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

and trying to use:

```
fs.writeFile(...);
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined
```

My rollup config:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'js/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'build/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourcemap: 'inline'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs()
  ],
  external: [
    'fs'
  ]
};
```

Comment: Why did you add `external`? This is the opposite of what you're trying to do.

Comment: How so? On another note, I removed it and ended up getting the same error.

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - a repo, etc. From what you've shown (except `external`), `import` should be translated to `require`, and you cannot get undefined from `require('fs')`. Btw, `iife` doesn't make much sense for Node, it likely should be `cjs`.

Comment: @interwebjill have you found a solution to this?